# Multiple signatures in a letter

Tags: letters

I've searched for this but haven't found a solution.  Is it possible to have multiple signatures in a letter, one above the other?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you tell how you write the letter: which document class (scrlttr2, letter, g-brief, dinbrief, lettre, ...) do you use and which code.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using the `letter` document class, simply insert this between the `\begin{document}` and the `\begin{letter}`:

```
\signature{Palpatine \\ Emperor \\ \vspace{1.5cm} Darth Vader \\ Lord of the Sith}
```

Comment: This applies to `dinbrief`. I used `\signature{Mary Sue\hspace{2cm}John Doe}` which I prefer over wasting vertical space.

Answer (score 9):

At a point, where you place the signature, you could also use a [parbox](http://texblog.net/help/latex/parbox.html) or a [minipage environment](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-267.html). So, replace `signature text` for example just by

```
\parbox{5cm}{signature one

signature two}
```

or

```
\parbox{5cm}{signature one\\signature two}
```

to get a two lines, even as argument to another command.

Another way would be to use a `tabular` environment to stack multiple signatures on top of each other.

Answer (score 8):

Old question but I was facing this problem today and I found a solution not mentioned here. I used a table within the signature and it worked perfectely.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\longindentation=1.5cm
\signature{
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
    Donnie Darko & Karen Pomeroy \\
    \end{tabular}
}

\address{Street Number \\ City \\ Country}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Dear Rabbit,}
This is a letter.
\closing{Best regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Using tabular it is possible to add several signatures and lines below or over to have more space for the signature or between the names:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\longindentation=1.5cm

\signature{
\begin{tabular}{c p{2cm} c}
~ & ~ & ~ \\
~ & ~ & ~ \\
Donnie Darko & ~ & Karen Pomeroy \\
Troubled Teenager & ~ & English Teacher\\
\end{tabular}
}

\address{Street Number \\ City \\ Country}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Dear Rabbit,}
This is a letter.
\closing{Best regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be helpful if you could turn this into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `scrlttr2` class you can overwrite the signature by defining in the preamble of the document:

```
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{signature}{Marie Curie \hspace{2cm} Pierre Curie}
```

The `renewcommand` is useful to prevent this [Strange behaviour of \closing in koma-script scrlttr2 class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152535/strange-behaviour-of-closing-in-koma-script-scrlttr2-class) .