# Strange behaviour of \closing in koma-script scrlttr2 class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script, scrlttr2

I'm having some trouble with the command `\closing{\closingphrase}`.

If `\closingphrase` is longer (e.g. 'Met vriendelijke groet'), the closing phrase is aligned left and the signature is indented.
This is the correct placing of the elements which conforms to the example in the Koma-script manual.

But if `\closingphrase` is relatively short (e.g. 'Hoogachtend'), the closing phrase is indented and the signature is aligned left, which looks very strange.

As it is customary in Dutch to end a formal letter with 'Hoogachtend' I'd like to prevent this from happening.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and help me prevent it?

**Example of strange alignment**

```
\documentclass[DIN,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\def\afzender{Richard Kranendonk}
\def\ondertekening{Cheers}
\setkomavar{signature}{\afzender}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}

Dear Sir,

This is a minimal test letter. 

\closing{\ondertekening,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a small example please.

Comment: You can add `\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}`. Does it help?

Comment: That _does_ put closingphrase and signature to the left, but outdented (more to the left than the body text). Which looks even stranger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marco Daniel already showed how to modify the behaviour of `scrlttr2`. The default behaviour is explained in section 21.1.7 of the [`KOMA-Script` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf):

> Closing phrase and signature will be typeset in a box. The width of
>   the box is determined by the length of the longest line of the closing
>   phrase or signature.

In other words, the closing phrase will be indented not if it is "relatively short", but if the phrase plus the appended comma is shorter than the signature.

Answer (score 10):

Here an example using `\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}`
. You have to use the mandatory argument of `letter` :

```
\documentclass[DIN,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\def\afzender{Richard Kranendonk}
\def\ondertekening{Cheers}
\setkomavar{signature}{\afzender}
\makeatletter
%\@setplength{sigindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Petra Mustermann\\ Vor dem Berg 1\\ 12345 Musterhausen}
\opening{Dear Sir}
\lipsum[1]
\closing{\ondertekening,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This aligns everything nicely to the left. Still, I don't think the alignment of closing phrase and signature are _supposed_ to be influenced this way by the length of closing phrase. But for practical purposes your solution works fine.